# Will shifting into drive while accelerating in neutral damage my engine?

Tags: engine, transmission

I was at a traffic signal with my car on nuetral. When the lights turned green, I accelerated without realising the car was still on nuetral. I then immediately shifted into drive while the engine was revving. My car jerked initially but then drove normally. I didn't realise any abnormalities after that while driving.

I'm worried I may have damaged my transmission. Will shifting into drive while accelerating usually damage transmission or is it something I dont have to worry about.

My car is a 2016 Honda Accord coupe (Automatic transmission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if done excessively, it is possible to damage your car doing this, you could -

- break a CV joint
- break a universal joint
- strip a driveshaft spline
- damage the gearbox
- tear a rubber coupling
- damage an engine mount

and probably damage a number of other things.

If the car is driving as normal, then I wouldn't worry about it.  If you start hearing knocking noises after doing this, then you need to get the car checked.

Comment: No clue who downvoted, but gave my uptick for a good answer to counteract.

Answer (score 0):

Once probably won't damage it unless you are unlucky.

Doing this repeatedly will eventually cause damage sooner or later and that is usually a transmission out and overhaul / replacement - which is not cheap...

Comment: Probably "sooner".

Comment: I did twist off the transmission tailshaft on a hydromatic  doing that; However i was very young an foolish at the time.  and did not repeat.